# vscode remote ssh integrated terminal not reading correct python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh

I followed the instructions on how to set up a remote ssh development environment.  I have a host: windows 10.  I go to my terminal and ssh into a remote linux server for python development.  When i remote in for the first time, its a fresh new environment.  When i type

```
which python
```

I receive usr/bin/python.

I then copy a bash_profile located at a custom directory into the root directory and log off the remote session ang log back in and type

```
which python
```

I receive alias python='/opt/anaconda2/bin/python2.7'
/opt/anaconda2/bin/python2.7

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

gives me /opt/Iceetcetc-3.4.2_51/python:/home/myusername/dev/py:/opt/py:/opt/html

then when i type python i see the following on my remote session:

Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda Inc.| (default, Oct 16 2017) [GCC 7.2.8] on linux2

import company_module

works fine

Now, from my local host, a windows machine, i started a new vscode and pressed "connect to remote host" i type in my username@hostname with the requisite password and I'm logged in.  When click on 'new terminal' inside vscode, inside the integrated terminal, i typed hostname and see that i am on the same hostname.  However,

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

gives me a empty variable rather than /opt/Iceetcetc-3.4.2_51/python:/home/myusername/dev/py:/opt/py:/opt/html

How can i get the integrated environment get the same pythonpath as my remote shell?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your profile file is called .bashrc

```
dmitry@dmitry-Standard-PC-Q35-ICH9-2009:~$ pwd
/home/dmitry
dmitry@dmitry-Standard-PC-Q35-ICH9-2009:~$ cat .bashrc
export DmitryTest=WorksNow
```

And now in remote vscode

[image]

Comment: And make sure that you don't overwrite your .bashrc if it exists to start with.